# How Redirect to without slash?

Tags: redirect

I want redirect the page Blog

```
www.example.com/blog/ to www.example.com/blog
www.example.com/es/blog/ to www.example.com/es/blog
www.example.com/en/blog/ to www.example.com/en/blog
```

I have this, but doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/blog/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/en/blog/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/en/blog [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/es/blog/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/es/blog [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RewriteConditions are failing because of the invalid pattern :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/blog/$
```

The condition above says if the host value is **example.com/blog/** this condition returns false because http_Host represents the domain name only, part after the domain name is part of the Request_uri  and it can not be manipulated using http_host variable.

You can do it like this :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /blog [NC,L,R]
```

The example above redirects :

- example.com/blog/

to

- example.com/blog

If you want to remove the trailing slash for all requests excluding existent dirs ,you may use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on


#if trailing slash  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
 #redirect the request to remove the trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1 [L,R]
```